# Bidirectional iterators in unordered_map?

Tags: c++

The following minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>

int main()
{
        boost::unordered_map<int, int> m;
        boost::unordered_map<int, int>::const_iterator i;

        m.insert(std::make_pair(1, 2));

        i = m.end();
        --i;

        std::cout << i->first << " -> " << i->second << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

...fails to compile.

```
bidi.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
bidi.cxx:13: error: no match for ‘operator--’ in ‘--i’
```

According to [Boost's own documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/unordered/comparison.html):

> `iterator`, `const_iterator` are of at least the forward category.

It would appear that that's all they are. Why? What technical restriction does a hash-map impose that prevents iterators from being bidirectional?

(gcc version 4.1.2, Boost versions 1.40.0 and 1.43.0.)

Comment: This is pure speculation mind you, but keep in mind for you to be able to traverse something backwards AND forwards then each node would need to have a pointer to the next item AND the previous item. If this map were implemented with ONLY pointers to the next items, then your iterator would have no way to figure out what came before the current node, and thus no way to go backwards.

Comment: Honestly I find it kind of weird (though occasionally useful) that unordered_maps even have iterators.

Comment: @Niki Yoshiuchi:  I've used the corresponding concept in Perl a lot.  Usually, I want Perl hashes to function as associative arrays, but sometimes I want to do something to the whole hash.  In Perl, I use the `keys` function to get a list of the keys, and iterate through it, whereas in C++ the obvious equivalence is a forward iterator.  I'd really miss the ability to do the equivalent of `foreach` on any data collection.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no technical reason why an `unordered_map` can't have bidirectional iterators.  The main reason is that it would add additional cost to the implementation, and the designers thought nobody would really need bidirectional iterators in a hash map.  After all, there's no order in a hash, and so the order the iterator gives you is entirely arbitrary.  What would traversing a fixed but arbitrary order backwards give you?

Normally, one would access an `unordered_map` on an element-by-element basis, or traverse the whole map.  I've never done otherwise in Perl, myself.  To do this, a forward iterator is necessary, and therefore there is one in there, and Boost guarantees it.  To have bidirectional iterators, it would likely be necessary to include an additional pointer in each entry, which increases memory use and processing time.

I'm not coming up with a good, plausible, use case for bidirectional iterators here.  If you can, you can ask the Boost maintainers to consider it, although you're almost certainly too late for C++0x.

Comment: Actually, I thought the bit about hash-maps returning results in an arbitrary order was quite convincing. The usual use-cases are either a lookup, or complete iteration. In my head, they were always implemented with a vector of buckets, and a bucket being a std::list. Never considered the savings of possibly using a singly-linked-list.