# Why `std::prev` does not fire an error with an iterator of `std::unordered_set`?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

My question is related to the question linked below. 
[Bidirectional iterators in unordered_map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998452/bidirectional-iterators-in-unordered-map)

Since I did not know `std::unordered_set` does not support bidirectional iterators, I happened to write a code similar to this one.

```
int main(){
    unordered_set<int> y{4};
    std::cout << *(std::prev(y.end())) << std::endl;
}
```

This program is COMPILED, but the last line of the code crashed the program. Puzzled by that, I encountered the linked question. However, I still don't understand why this program is compiled instead of throwing error messages while the code in the linked code(which is `boost::unordered_set`) cannot be compiled. Could you clarify it?

FYI, I am using Mingw64 with g++ 4.8.2 / Windows 7 / 64 bit environment.

Comment: Boost != standard library (however many people may regard it as such).

Comment: Interesting. For non-BiDi iterators, `advance` could use an unsigned parameter, so that you get a warning when passing a signed argument. Additionally, `std::prev` could use a `static_assert` that you can decrement the iterator. Seems like a useful extension, it shouldn't have a runtime cost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::prev` only produces defined behavior for bidirectional iterators.

---

The GNU ISO C++ library (used by GCC 4.8.2) uses `std::advance` to implement `std::prev`, and `std::advance` itself is implemented like this:

- for random access iterators:

  ```
  __i += __n;
  ```
- for bidirectional iterators:

  ```
  if (__n > 0)
    while (__n--)
      ++__i;
  else
    while (__n++)
      --__i;
  ```
- for all other iterators:

  ```
  while (__n--)
    ++__i;
  ```

So you can see that for an iterator of `unordered_set`, the function actually does not use the `operator--` which produces the compiler error in the other question you linked.

---

It is your duty to make sure that an iterator passed to `std::prev` is bidirectional. If that is not the case the C++ standard does not give you any guarantees what happens. GCC chooses to just silently ignore it, but it might as well crash your program.

Comment: In debug mode there is a runtime assertion failure. Strangely enough the concept checking mode doesn't check std::prev, filing a request for enhancement in gcc's bugzilla would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

`std::prev` possibly uses `std::advance`, where, when the argument (Input Iterator) is not Bidirectional the behavior is undefined.

Comment: `std::prev` may use `std::advance` (and probably does), but this is UB however it's implemented. Although the library could (usefully) check the iterator type, it isn't required to, and in general the compiler isn't required to issue diagnostics for UB.

Comment: Unlike `std::prev`, it is allowed to pass a forward iterator to `std::advance`. But only if `n` is not negative (but it would of course be negative in the case that std::prev does use `std::advance`). I don't see how `std::advance` is relevant (to the user of `std::prev`). `std::prev` has precondition that iterator is at least bidirectional, `std::advance` has precondition that iterator is at least bidirectional if `n` is negative. Both have undefined behaviour if precondition is broken.